# Can't seem to write all the information to CSV file with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css

I'm trying to pull a specific header from a website with python script.  If I can get this working, I'll actually be pulling image names, but figured I would start with something simple like the header. I can pull the header name and save the date to a csv file, but the header name doesn't print.  To clarify, each time I save, the date saves to the file, but the header name doesn't.

Here is my python script:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv
import time
import os

def get_html():
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),    
    )

    opener.add_handler = [
        ('User-agent',
         "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; "
         "Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; "
         ".NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)")

    ]

    url = "http://www.photosbywagner.com/galleryone.html"
    response = opener.open(url)
    return ''.join(response.readlines())

def get_html_sections(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    html_section = soup.find('div',
            attrs={'id': 'headcontainer'})
    return html_section

def parse_section_html(html):
    selected_html = get_html_sections(html)
    result = {}

    # <img />
    result['selection'] = selected_html.find('h1').contents[0]

    return result

field_order = ['date', 'info']

fields = {'date' : 'Date',
          'info' : 'Info'}

def write_row(selected_html):
    file_name = "WrittenNames" + ".csv"
    if os.access(file_name, os.F_OK):
        file_mode = 'ab'
    else:
        file_mode = 'wb'

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
        open(file_name, file_mode),
        fieldnames=field_order,
        extrasaction='ignore',
    )

    if file_mode == 'wb':
        csv_writer.writerow(fields)
    csv_writer.writerow(selected_html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = get_html()
    row_to_write = parse_section_html(html)  
    row_to_write['date'] = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    write_row(row_to_write)
    print row_to_write
```

Here is the webpage:

http://www.photosbywagner.com/galleryone.html

the section I'm pulling is:

```
<div id="headcontainer"><h1>Ed Wagner Photo Gallery:</h1></div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, since everything else seems to check out - it pulls the right info and prints it to the screen, it just won't save to the CSV.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parse_section_html, should:

```
result['selection'] = selected_html.find('h1').contents[0]
```

be:

```
result['info'] = selected_html.find('h1').contents[0]
```

to match your fields definition?

Comment: OMG....I can't believe I missed that. I've been staring at it for too long, I think. Thank you!